# Double of a drilled out hyperbolic 3-manifold

Tags: geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, low-dimensional-topology

If one starts with a closed hyperbolic 3-manifold and removes the interior of a some number of solid tori. The resulting manifold with boundary can be doubled along its boundary.

Does this doubling always produce a hyperbolic 3-manifold?

If not always, what are the obstructions?

Comment: Never. Hint: First consider the case of one solid torus whose boundary is incompressible in the solid torus exterior. Then  analyze the compressible case.

Comment: I want to say that the doubling along the single incompressible torus boundary gives an incompressible torus in the double, so the double is not atoroidal, and not hyperbolic. I don't see why the incompressible boundary stays incompressible in the double though. Compressible boundary isn't possible as it would be a lens space.

Comment: The simplest way to get incompressibility is to observe that if $N$ is the double of a manifold $M$ across its boundary, then $M$ is a retract of $N$. Alternatively, one can use algebra (via van Kampen's Theorem).